# Perl Cannot Find Module XML/Simple

Tags: 14.04, perl

I my attempting to run a Perl script on Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS. The script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.18.2

use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use Net::Telnet();
```

I get the following on the command line:

```
Can't locate XML/Simple.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::Simple module)
(@INC contains: /usr/share/perl5/ /etc/perl 
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 
/usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .)
at RR_2_668.pl line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at RR_2_668.pl line 16.
```

The XML::Simple is on line 16. I removed all the comment lines in between
and removed addition code after for brevity. I did a search and the Simple.pm seems
to be on the system:

```
/usr/share/perl5/IPC/System/Simple.pm
/usr/share/perl5/Lintian/Command/Simple.pm
/usr/share/perl5/Log/Message/Simple.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.18.2/Locale/Maketext/Simple.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.18.2/Pod/Simple.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.18.2/Test/Simple.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.18.2/Filter/Simple.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.18.2/Log/Message/Simple.pm
```

Is there a way to get my script to see one of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the `Simple.pm` files you've found belong to other Perl libraries. None of them do what you want. You have found

```
IPC::System::Simple
Lintian::Command::Simple
Log::Message::Simple
Locale::Maketext::Simple
Pod::Simple
Test::Simple
Filter::Simple
Log::Message::Simple
```

To find the right one you should do `apt-cache search XML::Simple` and pick a package to install with `sudo apt-get install <insert your choice>`.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 (YMMV), it shows me:

```
$ apt-cache search XML::Simple
libxml-simple-perl - Perl module for reading and writing XML
libdns-zoneparse-perl - Perl extension for parsing and manipulating DNS Zone Files
libgtk2-gladexml-simple-perl - clean object-oriented perl interface to Gtk2::GladeXML
libtemplate-plugin-xml-perl - XML plugins for the Template Toolkit
libtest-xml-simple-perl - Perl testing framework for XML data
libxml-libxml-simple-perl - Perl module that uses the XML::LibXML parser for XML structures
libxml-opml-simplegen-perl - module for creating OPML using XML::Simple
libxml-simpleobject-enhanced-perl - Perl module which enhances libxml-simpleobject-perl
libxml-simpleobject-libxml-perl - Simple oo representation of an XML::LibXML DOM object
libxml-simpleobject-perl - Objectoriented Perl interface to a parsed XML::Parser tree
ruby-xml-simple - Simple Ruby API for reading and writing XML
libxml-hash-lx-perl - module to convert hash to xml and vice versa using LibXML
libxml-struct-perl - represent XML as data structure preserving element order
libxml-structured-perl - Convert XML data into a predefined Perl data structure and back
```